# detectar si se aprieta cancelar en un InputBox para ingresar un Integer en Vb 6.0

Tags: vb6

A los efectos de depurar un programa necesito saber la forma detectar cuando el usuario pulsa el botón Cancelar de un Inputbox
He visto que hay muchas formas de hacer esto, pero en todas se hace uso de una variable tipo String.
El problema es que necesito que el contenido del inputbox a evaluar sea un número (dato tipo Integer) y no un String.
Esto lo que pensé:

```
Dim numero As Integer
numero = InputBox ("Ingrese un número")
If chr(numero) = vBNullString Then
     MsgBox "Ha presionado Cancelar"
Else
     MsgBox "Ha presionado Aceptar y el número ingresado fue " & numero
End If
```

Comment: El inputbox siempre devuelve una cadena.. si lo que devuelve esta vacio, podes suponer que apreto cancelar.. asi que mejor, primero fijate si lo que devolvio tiene algo... es mas.. si en tu inputbox alguien escribe un texto, el problema es el mismo...

Comment: no se a que te referis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Texto_A_Valor()

'Esta es la forma para poder usar una variable de tipo valor (Integer o Double)

Dim Texto As String
Dim Valor As Double

Texto = InputBox("Ingrese la Cantidad")

If Texto = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Ha presionado Cancelar"
Else
    Valor = Val(Texto)
    MsgBox "Ha presionado Aceptar y la cantidad es " & Valor
    
'Aquí simplemente descargo el Valor en una celda y compruebo que tanto
'Enteros como Decimales se cargan correctamente

    Hoja5.Range("I14").Value = Valor
    
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim numero As String
numero = InputBox("Ingrese un número")
If Len(numero) And IsNumeric(numero) Then
     MsgBox"Ha presionado Aceptar y el número ingresado fue " & numero 
Else
     MsgBox "Ha presionado Cancelar"
End If
```

Comment: Considera editar tu respuesta para explicar qué hace el código. Pegar un bloque de código no es una respuesta de calidad. Ten en cuenta que si se ingresa cualquier texto no numérico tu propuesta dará el mensaje `Ha presionado Cancelar` y no sería cierto.

Comment: igual me sirvió

Comment: Pära que no tire error puse If Not (Len(numero)) And Not (IsNumeric(numero)) Then Exit Sub

Answer (score 0):

No es posible controlar el botón cancelar si se define una variable inputbox como Integer, pues un InputBox siempre devuelve un tipo de dato String.
Siempre la variable del inputBox se debe definir como String

Sin embargo, este enfoque combina InputBox y el manejo de errores en una sola declaración If, lo que hace que sea más difícil de leer y mantener. Generalmente se recomienda utilizar una función separada para una mejor legibilidad y organización del código. No obtante si no de desea usar una función separada, este ejemplo muestra una forma de hacerlo.

```
Dim numero As Variant
numero = InputBox("Ingrese un número")
If numero = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "Ha presionado Cancelar"
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    numero = CInt(numero)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "El valor ingresado no es un número válido."
        numero = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End If

If Not IsError(numero) Then
    MsgBox "Ha presionado Aceptar y el número ingresado fue " & numero
End If
```